# Upgrade to nuxt-bridge: Auto-imports cause eslint errors

Tags: nuxt.js, eslint, vue-composition-api, nuxt-bridge

I want to upgrade a nuxt `v2.16` project to `v2.17` and `nuxt-bridge` and replace the `@nuxt/composition-api` with the core composition api.

Now I have autoimports and this code for example runs:

```js
// ...
  setup(props) {
    const { content } = toRefs(props)
    const { env, $axios, $moment } = useNuxtApp()
    const filters = ref()
    const fetching = ref(false)
```

but eslint still complains about these: `toRefs`, `useNuxtApp`, `ref` like `'useNuxtApp' is not defined. eslint no-undef`.

How can I overcome this problem? I think the eslint should take into account that it should not complain about auto-imports.

Comment: I found a solution, with a bloated eslintrc:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/16871#discussioncomment-2284786